# Automator action to adjust volume on audio files

Tags: audio, automator

I am looking for an Automator action (or an app with Automator support) that can adjust the volume on audio files (something like set to 150% of input file volume), preferably free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like [SoX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/) (free/donationware). It's [features page](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features) lists wide variety of volume/level effects, including:

> - Volume/level effects
>
>   - ...
>   - ...
>   - vol: Adjust audio volume

According to the [SoX documentation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html), the following should double the volume of `input.wav` and write it to `output.wav` (the value after the -v flag is a multiplier)

`sox -v 2.0 input.wav output.wav`

You should be able to use this in an Automator workflow using the "Run Shell Script" action.